HotChocolate AND filtering in DateTime Enumerable
In my c# HotChocolate graphql app (HotChocolate.AspNetCore version 13.5.1) I have the following class containing an Enumerable with DateTimes.
public class MyData {

    ...
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> MyDates { get; set; } = new List<DateTime>();
}

I want to get all entries where the myDates contains an entry that is between 2 specific dates. For that I am trying the following query in my Playground.
query {
    getMyData
        (first: 10, 
         where: { myDates: { some: {gt: "2016-02-23", lt: "2016-02-25"}}}) 
    { ... }
}

Examples:
MyDates: [ "2016-02-22", "2016-02-24", "2016-02-26"] should be found.
MyDates: [ "2016-02-22", "2016-02-26"] should not be found.
The problem is that both entries are found, because somehow the "gt" and "lt" are being executed as OR and not as AND.
My query is configured like this:
[ExtendObjectType("Query")]
public class MyDataQuery
{
    [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true)]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public IQueryable<MyData> GetMyData([Service] ISomeService service)
    {
        if (service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
        return service.GetMyData());
    }
}

In my Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType(d => d.Name("Query"))
    .AddTypeExtension<MyDataQuery>()
    .AddProjections()
    .AddFiltering()
    .AddSorting()
    .ModifyRequestOptions(opt => opt.IncludeExceptionDetails = 
true);


I set up a quick instance of HotChocolate with the information you provided but I cannot seem to reproduce the issue. If I run the same query (minus the first) I only get the item that has dates that are in range of the gt/lt. query { myData (where: { myDates: { some: {gt: "2016-02-23", lt: "2016-02-25"}}}) { myDates } }

Would you be able to share some more info about your configuration of HotChocolate?

What kind of configuration are you looking for?^^

The funny part is, that i have another property inside the MyData class that is a DateTime. When I call the combination of gt/lt on that property everything works fine. Just the array seems to make the issue

How is the query set up? Are you using annotations, or code-first when setting up the query? What version of HotChocolate are you using?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Case closed.
The filtering worked fine. I was missing a property inside my "HasKey()" definition of my entity.
Therefore the HasMany relationship always had only one entry inside the myDates enumerable.
It looked like the filtering did not work, but somehow HotChocolate found the right entries, but was missing some myDates entries.
